# R function-- the default value does not work?

Tags: r

I am really new to R. Allow me to ask a beginner's question.

When I type p.adjust, for example, I can see the following. It seems that the argument method is p.adjust.methods by default. I tried to trace the code but when I typed something like:

```
match.arg(p.adjust.methods)
```

It says:

> Error in match.arg(p.adjust.methods) : 'arg' must be of length 1

Why?

```
> p.adjust
function (p, method = p.adjust.methods, n = length(p)) 
{
    method <- match.arg(method)
    ...
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `p.adjust`? It sounds like it's complaining that you haven't specified a value for the second argument, specifying the correction method.

Does it behave as you expect when you specify a value for that parameter? For example: `p.adjust(p, "holm")` (assuming that `p` contains your vector of _p_-values)

Comment: It works as expected. I just tried to understand how the function p.adjust() works and I was previously stuck at the first line, namely, method <- match.arg(method). I thought it is the same as method <- match.arg(p.adjust.methods) if I don't provide any thing to the 2nd argument in p.adjust(). But now I understand that match.arg can not be used in an interactive way.

Answer (score 7):

The `match.arg` function does not work in interactive mode in its one argument form, since there is nothing to match to. That first argument is expected to be a length 1 character vector, and it is tested against the known methods _inside_the_function_:

```
> ?p.adjust
> p.adjust.methods
[1] "holm"       "hochberg"   "hommel"     "bonferroni" "BH"         "BY"         "fdr"       
[8] "none"
```

(The first argument to `p.adjust` if you are using positional matching needs to be a vector of p-values.)

Comment: Pedantically, you can use `match.arg` interactively; it just needs two arguments.  For example, `match.arg("hol", p.adjust.methods)`.  The 1 argument version just tries to retrieve the choices from the formal arguments of the parent function.